# printing address of the character array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Please tell me how `char*arr[4]`, `char *(*ptr)[4]=&arr` and `(*ptr)[i]` signify here step by step.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i;
char *arr[4]={"c","c++","java","vba"};
char *(*ptr)[4]=&arr;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
       printf("address of string %d : %u\n",i+1,(*ptr)[i]);
return 0;
}

output:
address of string 1 : 178
address of string 2 : 180
address of string 3 : 184
address of string 4 : 189
```

and if I change printf statement:

```
printf("string %d : %s\n",i+1,(*ptr)[i]);

output:
string 1 = c
string 2 = c++
string 3 = java
string 4 = vba
```

also give me some links where I can find similar questions for practice.

Comment: I doubt the second output in your question does refer to `printf("string %d : %s\n",i+1,*(ptr)[i]);`. More likely it the outcome of `printf("string %d : %s\n",i,(*ptr)[i]);`.

Comment: @alk; Agreed. `printf("string %d : %s\n",i+1,*(ptr)[i]);` is giving some garbage value. But since behavior is undefined he may get this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *arr[4]` is an array of 4 pointers to char. In other words it is array of 4 strings.
`char *(*ptr)[4]=&arr` declares a pointer to array of 4 pointers to char. The assignement in this line assigns the address of the first element of the array `arr`;
`*(ptr)[i]` dereferences the ith element of the `ptr` array.

I've just found a [quiz](http://www.cquestions.com/2010/06/c-questions-on-pointers.html) on tricky C pointer declarations. You can practice there.

Comment: "*char *(*ptr)[4]=&arr declares an array of 4 pointers to strings*". No, it declares a pointer to such.

Comment: @alk Indeed. Thanks for noticing the mistake! I updated the answer.

Comment: It's not an array of four strings but of four pointers to such.

Comment: @alk `[]` have higher precedence than `*` so `char *arr[4]` is equivalent to `char *(arr[4])` which is array of 4 `char*`s, i.e. array of 4 strings.

Comment: A string is a `char` array` and `arr` is an array of pointers to `char`, with each element referencing a sperate area of memeory, where those 4 areas not necessarily are continous areas of memory.

Comment: @alk `char *(*ptr)[4]` declare `ptr` as a pointer to array of 4 pointers to `char`.

Comment: Yes, but the 4 arrays of char referenced by `arr` are not linear but scattered around the memory. The only linear thing are the 4 char pointers in `arr`.

Comment: @alk; Not necessary that all 4 char pointers are linear in memory.

Comment: By definition  in theoretical computer science, a string is a finite sequence of symbols that are chosen from a set called an alphabet. Thus the requirement of string being in a continuous area in memory is not the part of the string. On the other hand it is usual to call `char *` as string in C so I still think that statements in my answer are valid.

Answer (score -1):

This is the one of a good example of **undefined behavior**. Why?

The reason behind this is using wrong specifier for a particular data type always invokes undefined behavior.
`*(ptr)[i]` is of type `char *`. Printing it with the specifier `%u` is wrong.
Use `%p` specifier to print the pointer data type.

```
 printf("address of string %d : %p\n",i+1,(void *)*(ptr)[i]);
```

Comment: Still wrong... - `ptr` is a pointer to an array. So to access the array's elements **first** de-reference `ptr`. The latter is the cause of the "strange" behaviour.

Comment: Sure it's a pointer, but not the one the OP is longing for. Will say: The code you show would not result in the output expected.

Comment: Passing a `char*` for printing an `"%s"` is perfersclty valid.

Comment: Also loopng over `*(ptr)[i]` loops `(i= 0; i<4; ++i)` over 4 arrays of 4 `char*`s and not over the 4 `char*` elements of exactly one array..

Answer (score -1):

This

```
*(ptr)[i]
```

should be

```
(*ptr)[i]
```

And: Use `%p` to print `void *` pointers, so the printing line should look like:

```
printf("address of string %d : %p\n", i+1, (void *)(*ptr)[i]);
```

Comment: The question was not to correct the OPs code but rather to explain how "char*arr[4], char *(*ptr)[4]=&arr and *(ptr)[i] signify step by step".

Comment: @IgorPopov; If you downvoted this answer then I suggest you not to do like this. This is not the proper way. Question is not clear enough to us.